# How to scrape the text of <li> and children

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape the content of `<li>` tags and within them.

The HTML looks like:

```
 <div class="insurancesAccepted">
   <h4>What insurance does he accept?*</h4>
   <ul class="noBottomMargin">
      <li class="first"><span>Aetna</span></li>
      <li>
         <a title="See accepted plans" class="insurancePlanToggle arrowUp">AvMed</a>
         <ul style="display: block;" class="insurancePlanList">
            <li class="last first">Open Access</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a title="See accepted plans" class="insurancePlanToggle arrowUp">Blue Cross Blue Shield</a>
         <ul style="display: block;" class="insurancePlanList">
            <li class="last first">Blue Card PPO</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a title="See accepted plans" class="insurancePlanToggle arrowUp">Cigna</a>
         <ul style="display: block;" class="insurancePlanList">
            <li class="first">Cigna HMO</li>
            <li>Cigna PPO</li>
            <li class="last">Great West Healthcare-Cigna PPO</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
         <a title="See accepted plans" class="insurancePlanToggle arrowUp">Empire Blue Cross Blue Shield</a>
         <ul style="display: block;" class="insurancePlanList">
            <li class="last first">Empire Blue Cross Blue Shield HMO</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

The main issue is when I am trying to get content from:

```
doc.css('.insurancesAccepted li').text.strip
```

It displays all `<li>` text at once. I want "AvMed" and "Open Access" **scraped** at the same time with a relationship parameter so that I can insert it into my MySQL table with reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `doc.css('.insurancesAccepted li')` matches *all* nested list items, not only direct descendants. To match only a direct descendant one should use a `parent > child` CSS rule. To accomplish your task you need to carefully assemble the result of the iteration:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
result = doc.css('div.insurancesAccepted > ul > li').each do |li|
  chapter = li.css('span').text.strip
  section = li.css('a').text.strip
  subsections = li.css('ul > li').map(&:text).map(&:strip)

  puts "#{chapter} ⇒ [ #{section} ⇒ [ #{subsections.join(', ')} ] ]"
  puts '=' * 40
end
```

Resulted in:

```
# Aetna ⇒ [  ⇒ [  ] ]
# ========================================
#  ⇒ [ AvMed ⇒ [ Open Access ] ]
# ========================================
#  ⇒ [ Blue Cross Blue Shield ⇒ [ Blue Card PPO ] ]
# ========================================
#  ⇒ [ Cigna ⇒ [ Cigna HMO, Cigna PPO, Great West Healthcare-Cigna PPO ] ]
# ========================================
#  ⇒ [ Empire Blue Cross Blue Shield ⇒ [ Empire Blue Cross Blue Shield HMO ] ]
# ========================================
```

Comment: hi its throwing following error " syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
  p "#{chapter} ⇒ [#{section} ⇒ [#{subsections.join(', ')} ] ]" "